# (Beginner question) How to solve large gradient region from experimental data?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, fitting

I have a data like this.

```
data ={100, 103, 101, 105, 100, 80, 83, 70, 71, 60, 40, 43, 20, 22, 10, 5, -1, -3, -2, 0, 1, 4, 3, 8, 7, 4, 3, 1, 0, 1, 2, 10, 5, 2}
```

Although the data values are fracturing, I want to extract the x region, with the large gradient. (The answer is 4<=x<=18)

I tried the FindFit, Interpolation... but I could not get the position.
Please tell me how to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may simply look at the smoothed differences between sequential data.

```
n = 4;
dif = Differences[data]
ListPlot[{dif = MovingAverage[dif, n]}]
```

[image]

Then you select the ones you want and get the min/max index of these data:

```
vals=Select[dif, # < -3 &];
MinMax[(Position[dif, #] & /@ vals // Flatten ) + n - 1 ]
(* {5, 17} *)
```

Comment: Thank you Very Much!! I didn't know the command Select and Differences. I will remember the usage of Position conbined with Minmax, which is very helpful.